# how to add the value from the next row to the current row

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to group by `id` column and add the value from the next row to the current row only for the `trip` column
How can I transform the first data frame to the second data frame shown below?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if the only thing requested is to concatenate the trip ID of the next row to the current row but if it is, would you consider using shift(-1) ?

```
df['newtrip']=df['trip']+'-'+df['trip'].shift(-1)
```

Comment: thanks a lot!!  df['trip']=df['trip']+'-'+df.groupby('id')['trip'].shift(-1)